# AtomiceInteger is not increased as expected with forjointask

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic

I am using AtmoicInteger inside a forkjointask to count have many times it reached the start condition.But the AtomicInteger was never updated with incrementAndGet().Detail code as following, anything i did wrong?

```
package Chapter7;

import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PrcForkJoinTask extends RecursiveAction {
    private int start , end;
    AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
    public PrcForkJoinTask(int start, int end){
        this.start =  start;
        this.end   = end;   
    }
    @Override
    protected void compute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(end - start <= 2 ){
            System.out.println("close condition reached" + "Start is " +  start +  "end is " +  end) ;
            System.out.println("calculated times"  +  count.getAndIncrement());
            }
    else{ 
        int middle = start + ((end - start) / 2);
      System.out.println("middle is " +  middle) ;
      invokeAll( new PrcForkJoinTask(start,middle),new PrcForkJoinTask(middle,end));

            }       
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){

        ForkJoinTask<?> fs =  new PrcForkJoinTask(0,10);

        ForkJoinPool  pool = new ForkJoinPool();

        pool.invoke(fs);    
    }
}
```

Comment: *But the AtomicInteger was never updated with incrementAndGet()*. What was the expected output? What was the actual output?

Comment: count.getAndIncrement()  this one did update. since the task will be splited to 6 tasks. the expected result for this 'count' is 6.

Comment: And what is the actual result?

Comment: it print 1 for count for 6 times.it means it comes the inscrement 6 times. but not really update it. that is strange for me. I also tried to change it to incrementAndGet but still the same.

Comment: You've got one AtomicInteger per TASK, not one shared between all tasks.  So each gets incremented to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time in recursion at line

```
invokeAll( new PrcForkJoinTask(start,middle),new PrcForkJoinTask(middle,end));
```

it will create new objects with new AtomicInteger count = 0  and then it will be increased by 1 at line

```
 System.out.println("calculated times"  +  count.getAndIncrement());
```

So multiple new objects PrcForkJoinTask will be created and each of them will have count = 1

If you want to calculate summary you need to pass count inside of new PrcForkJoinTask objects.